# text files with string arrays get position substring

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with the following:

I am loading a file into C# and then I am splitting it by lines with this code.

```
// Splitting by line from original file
string[] lines = showText.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Now I need a for loop that will go through `lines` and get `Substring` from those lines, separately.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish, in a way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    int[] testing = new int[i];
    testing[i] = int.Parse(lines[i].Substring(16, 1));
    textBox1.Text = testing.ToString();
}
```

The error here is: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Here is a picture also to get better idea as to what I'm trying to do.

http://s30.postimg.org/jbmjmqv1t/work.jpg

```
textBox1.Text = lines[0].Substring(16,1) + "   " + lines[0].Substring(23,9);
textBox1.Text = lines[1].Substring(16,1) + "   " + lines[1].Substring(23,9); //etc
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Post a line or two of actual data. Post it exactly as it appears. Either there is a bad line of data or your counting is off.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the array in the for loop, so it is being created for each line and with the wrong length. Instead of this part of the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    int[] testing = new int[i];
    testing[i] = int.Parse(lines[i].Substring(16, 1));
    textBox1.Text = testing.ToString();
}
```

you should be doing this:

```
int[] testing = new int[lines.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    testing[i] = int.Parse(lines[i].Substring(16, 1));
    textBox1.Text = testing.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've solved it.

```csharp
int[] testing = new int[lines.Length];

textBox1.Clear(); //Just to clear it if button pressed again
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    testing[i] = int.Parse(lines[i].Substring(16, 1));//just getting the needed value
    textBox1.Text += testing[i].ToString() + "\r\n" ;//adding each value to textBox1, separated by new line
}
```